# How to removed the displayed text in a console application, c#?

Tags: c#, if-statement, console, console-application

Suppose a user is asked for the manual. Now we all know that manuals are handy and extensive, how do I collapse/clear for instance so that the user can proceed to the next activity? By pressing C after pressing M, I want the user to immediately jump to the next acitivity.

How do I remove this?
[image: RemoveText]

Here is the code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Do you want to play the game?\nPress Y to continue\tPress M to view the rules\tEnter any key to exit. ");

            string iQuestion = Console.ReadLine();
            if (iQuestion.Equals("y", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                ProjectExecution();
                Console.WriteLine("\nWorld you like to try again?\nPress y to play again\tEnter any key to exit. ");
                string ask = Console.ReadLine();
                if (ask.Equals("y", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                {
                    ProjectExecution();
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Thank you for playing");
                }
                Console.Read();
            }
            else if (iQuestion.Equals("m", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Hwewewe\nPress C to continue");\\This is just an example
                string mQuestion = Console.ReadLine();
                if (mQuestion.Equals("c", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                {
                    Console.Clear();
                    ProjectExecution();
                    Console.Read();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Environment.Exit(10);
            }
        }
```

I am open to another solution.

Comment: Use `ReadKey` instead of `ReadLine`

Comment: Did not work friend